# Javascript - is null or true - What would be the most elegant solution?

Tags: javascript, null, boolean

Since we all know null is evaluated as false, how could I write "is null or true" in Javascript?
I have tried:

```
function isNullOrTrue(nullableBool){
  return !(nullableBool != null && nullableBool != true);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `v === null || v`…? (If *truthy* is desired, else `... v === true`.)

Comment: If your nullableBool can only ever be true, false or null, then `v !== false` would do it. Otherwise `v === null || v === true` or `[null, true].includes(v)`

Comment: Another way (checking for truthyness and handling undefined like null though) would be `v ?? true`

Comment: @CherryDT Make that an answer and earn some quick votes :-)

Comment: I always feel like one-liners I wrote on the go aren't "ripe" for an answer where I'd like to link docs, show example inputs and outputs and stuff. Feel free to edit it into your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

If the three possible inputs are only `null`, `true` and `false`, you can use

```
return nullableBool !== false
```

but explicitly listing the matching values isn't bad for readability either

```
return v === null || v === true
```

Using [`===` instead of `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1048572) isn't actually necessary here, as `null != false` (whereas `Boolean(null) == false`), but it might help for clarity if you're not familiar with the loose equality rules.

Answer (score 2):

The elegant solution to `is null or true` is to use [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
return nullableBool ?? true
```

It will return true if `nullableBool` is either `null` or `undefined`. Otherwise, it will return the value of `nullableBool`. If you only want to return `true` or `false`, then you can use double bang:

```
return !!(nullableBool ?? true)
```

Now, it will return `true` if `nullableBool` is either `null`, `undefined` or truthy value. Otherwise, return `false`.